# How to apply virtualenv python interpreter automatically by pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv

Whenever I make new project by pycharm, I tried to apply new python interpreter for the project manually for virtulenv.

I'm so tired of this kind of repetitive work, and since python executable is always on fixed location(e.g. my_project/bin/python) I imagine this could be set automatically.

Anybody know how to achieve my workflow by pycharm?

Comment: how many projects are you creating where this is becoming an issue? There may be another way of "solving" the disease of the problem instead of the symptom.

Comment: @MattR It's so old thread though, I got over than 30 projects and have more than average one new project per week. I fix my workflow using venv plugin.